# Generating a unqiue name for build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins for CI/CD implementation, I have gone through multiple forums and tried to set the name for the build generated by a job using build-name setter plugin in Jenkins.

Is there any way I could set the name for the Jenkins build with the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use this plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin
you can evaluate build name first in 'execute shell' step, e.g. by doing that:

```
MY_CUSTOM_NAME=$(date)
```

and then in Build Setter Plugin options, within 'Build Name' specify

```
${MY_CUSTOM_NAME}
```